# Ffmpeg hangs when -vcodec copy specified (called from Java via ProcessBuilder)

Tags: java, file, file-io, ffmpeg

I'm trying to use ffmpeg to export an array of bytes to a video file, but the people I work with insist that I use `-vcodec copy` in the arguments for it. This, however, causes the code to hang, whereas if I don't use -vcodec copy, the code will not hang. I don't know what the problem is, and I've been trying to debug this code for the past two hours.

Here is the relevant section of code. I've added comments above and below the line where the code hangs. Can anybody help me?

```
        // This is the tricky part. We need to build an ffmpeg process that
        // takes input from stdin, and then plug Java into that.
        ProcessBuilder ffmpegBuilder = new ProcessBuilder();
        String[] cmd = {"ffmpeg", "-i", "-","-vcodec", "copy", directory
                + "/" + fileName};
        StringBuilder combinedCmd = new StringBuilder();
        for (String s : cmd) {
            combinedCmd.append(s);
            combinedCmd.append(" ");
        }
        mLogger.log(Level.INFO,"Final command is " + combinedCmd.toString());
        ffmpegBuilder.command(cmd);
        ffmpegBuilder.redirectErrorStream(true); // So that stdout and stderr go
                                                    // to the same stream.
        byte[] dataToWrite = new byte[data.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < dataToWrite.length; i++) {
            dataToWrite[i] = data.get(i); // Is there really STILL no better way
                                            // to convert an ArrayList to an
                                            // array?!
        }
        try {
            Process ffmpeg = ffmpegBuilder.start();
            OutputStream stdin = ffmpeg.getOutputStream();
            BufferedReader stdout = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    ffmpeg.getInputStream()));
//HANGS AT THIS LINE vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
            stdin.write(dataToWrite);
//HANGS AT THIS LINE ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

            String line = "I know a song that gets on everybody's nerves...";
            while ((line != null) && stdout.ready()) {
                line = stdout.readLine();
                mLogger.log(Level.INFO, line);
            }
            try {
                ffmpeg.waitFor(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                ffmpeg.destroyForcibly();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried running the command in a command line ? What does ffmpeg says ?

If you don't use -vcodec copy, ffmpeg is going to reencode the video with a default codec and you probably don't want that.

Comment: I can't do that because the Java program is plugging in a byte array that it receives via UDP broadcast (which I'm simulating myself via multicast).

Comment: Can't you use ffmpeg udp input then ? ffmpeg -i udp://[multicast-address]:port

Comment: Ok. I'll try that and get back to you.

Comment: Ok. I used the following commands:
Transmit: `ffmpeg -i test.mp4 -f mpeg udp://239.105.3.25:55015`
Receive: `ffmpeg -i udp://239.105.3.25:55015 -vcodec copy out.mp4`

Apart from the usual output from ffmpeg, I also got this strange message: `[mp4 @ 0x3094780] pts has no value`

Any idea what that means? I also had to manually stop the input. Because the command is actually running in the Java program, my guess is that I need to kill the task after a while.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that the program was hanging halfway through writing the data. There is an awful lot of data there, and I knew there was something wrong at this point, so I tried to tell the java process to start reading stdout from the BufferedReader I had made. That fixed things. It turns out that the BufferedReader was filling up, and that because stdout had nowhere to go, the entire process hung. I changed the line that was hanging to this code here:

```
for (int i = 0;i < dataToWrite.length;i++) {
    stdin.write(dataToWrite[i]);
    if (stdout.ready()) {
        String line = stdout.readLine();
        mLogger.log(Level.INFO, line);
    }
}
```

That fixed everything.